# Unable to post data using HttpURLConnection, getting 404 file not found exception in Android

Tags: android

I have written a code to register a user or post some data but i am unable to post the data as i am getting 404 file not found exception.

```
Class A.java 

Map<String, Object> param = new LinkedHashMap<>();
param.put("UserName", user.getUser_name());
param.put("Password", user.getPassword());
param.put("EmailId", user.getEmailid());
param.put("MobileNo", "NA");
String str_url = 
"http://syncroft.in/SupervisorProductivity/RegisterUser"
AsyncTaskPost asyncTaskPost = new 
AsyncTaskPost(context,param,str_url,Register.this);
asyncTaskPost.execute();


AsyncTaskPost.java

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = CustomHttpClient.post(url, 
        localparams);
        jsonresult = jsonObject.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

CustomHttpClient.java

public static JSONObject post(String str_url, Map<String,Object> 
    params) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf
        (param.getValue()), 
        "UTF-8"));
    }
    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    URL url = new URL(str_url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
    String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream dStream = new 
    DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    dStream.writeBytes(postData.toString());
    dStream.flush();
    dStream.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder returnvalue = new StringBuilder();

    while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
        returnvalue.append(line);
    }
    br.close();

    JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(returnvalue.toString());

    conn.disconnect();
    return responseObj;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong as i am getting 404 as response code , File not found exception. The above Url is working in postman but does not work in java code.

Comment: Where are you posting to? Php?

Comment: web service is in c#

Comment: Then.. Which file is not found? I see no file in your url.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just call a wrong api or this is an api issue that server side must handle this.